# Pivot a table in DAX and sum column by groups

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I read in data from an ODBC source, and created measures based on the values of various columns in the data source using DAX formulas. I then created a new table to try to pivot it from this wide version
[image: Wide Version]

to this.
[image: Ideal Output]

I've tried this code and may variations of it but I only get something that aggregates by indicator, not by indicator, month, and Code.

```
risk - MTD = UNION(
SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER('RSQL', 'RSQL'[CV] >=0), "FacilityCode", 'RSQL'[FacilityCode], "Month", 'RSQL'[Month], "IndicatorName", "CV"),
SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER('RSQL', 'RSQL'[Closed] >=0), "FacilityCode", 'RSQL'[FacilityCode], "Month", 'RSQL'[Month], "IndicatorName", "CP"),
SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER('RSQL', 'RSQL'[EF] >=0), "FacilityCode", 'RSQL'[FacilityCode], "Month", 'RSQL'[Month], "IndicatorName", "EF"),
SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER('RSQL', 'RSQL'[IOF] >=0), "FacilityCode", 'RSQL'[FacilityCode], "Month", 'RSQL'[Month], "IndicatorName", "IOF"),
SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER('RSQL', 'RSQL'[MRP] >=0), "FacilityCode", 'RSQL'[FacilityCode], "Month", 'RSQL'[Month], "IndicatorName", "MRP"),
SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER('RSQL', 'RSQL'[MR] >=0), "FacilityCode", 'RSQL'[FacilityCode], "Month", 'RSQL'[Month], "IndicatorName", "MR"),
SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER('RSQL', 'RSQL'[OF] >=0), "FacilityCode", 'RSQL'[FacilityCode], "Month", 'RSQL'[Month], "IndicatorName", "OF"),
SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER('RSQL', 'RSQL'[AP] >=0), "FacilityCode", 'RSQL'[FacilityCode], "Month", 'RSQL'[Month], "IndicatorName", "AP"))
```

[image: resulting output]

How can I adjust my code to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
risk - MTD = UNION(
SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER('RSQL', 'RSQL'[CV] >=0), "FacilityCode", 'RSQL'[FacilityCode], "Month", 'RSQL'[Month], "IndicatorName", "CV", "Value", 'RSQL'[CV]),
SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER('RSQL', 'RSQL'[Closed] >=0), "FacilityCode", 'RSQL'[FacilityCode], "Month", 'RSQL'[Month], "IndicatorName", "CP", "Value", 'RSQL'[Closed]),
...,
...
)
```

[image]